# How to redirect route 53 dns to s3 static page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I searched a lot of similar questions and got more confused.

Basically my application is running on `https://example.com/login`. I have this DNS on route53. Now I want to display the "Under maintenance" page on the same URL.

So I created a static HTML page and hosted it in s3. Now if I am hitting `example.com` then I can access the static page but when I am hitting `https://example.com/login` or `http://example.com/login` I don't see the static page. Now I am having 2 questions:

1. Can I redirect example.com/login to example.com? so that my static page is visible.
2. Can I redirect https to HTTP or https://example.com/login to example.com?

I guess for https I have to use CloudFront but still checking if there is any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's possible, you shouldn't do it. Just use CloudFront with Route53 and ACM and host everything on HTTPS. [Here's an article how to do that](https://medium.com/@crishantha/connecting-your-website-securely-via-aws-route-53-cloudfront-and-acm-eb442ede7ef5), but you can find a lot of other ones.

The steps you need:

- request a new certificate on ACM (make sure you use the us-east-1 region). Select domain validation, then add the CNAME record to the domain
- create a new CloudFront distribution, add the S3 bucket as the origin, select "redirect HTTP to HTTPS", then add the alternate domain name as your domain (example.com) and select the ACM certificate
- add an A and an AAAA record in the Route53 hosted zone, make them an ALIAS to the distribution
- wait a few minutes and it should work

Using HTTP marks the connection as "Not secure" by the browser and a login form is especially something you want to serve over an encrypted connection. You need to set up CloudFront once, and you can add new files to the S3 bucket.